# How to work out if a diode's reverse recovery time is good enough?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, pwm

I'm designing a circuit using high frequency PWM signals and I was told to consider the reverse recovery time of the diodes I'm using

Would I be correct in assuming, from my understanding of reverse recovery time that:
If I have a PWM signal coming in at for example 20kHz like in the circuit below, then that means the voltage across the resistor will change every 50uS *

*(As: T = 1/F = 1/20k = 50uS)

So the required diode reverse recovery time would 50us or less

Is this a correct assumption?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f70l8D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: With the circuit as shown, the diode never gets forward biased, so there should not be ANY reverse recovery time; am I missing something important?

Comment: S = Siemens (1/ohm). s = second.

Comment: IF you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve you are MUCH more likely to get useful advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the load in your diagram isn't resistive (and is really inductive so that the diode is forward biased at some point)?

You want the diode to recover in a very small fraction of the switching cycle time.  Remember that while the diode is in recovery it's close to a short circuit.

On many fast recovery diodes you can find the recovery charge, Qrr, which tells you the amount of charge you have to supply to "recover" the diode.  You have to do this every cycle, so you can get a rough estimate the losses due to the reverse recovery by P = QRR * Vin * Fsw / 2.

You probably want the diode recovery losses to be a very small impact to the efficiency of your supply/circuit, so you can use the formula above to make sure the losses don't account for more than say a fraction of a percent of efficiency loss.  You should also pay attention to the extra thermal load from recovery.

A diode that recovers very quickly with a sharp recovery characteristic can cause ringing and EMI problems, so faster isn't always better.  "Soft recovery" diodes can help with EMI and still provide acceptable performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on recovery time it's very helpful. Ignore the circuit not making sense I think it must be wrong, I'm still trying to work out what I'm designing and why I was told to put a diode there. Can I just ask where Fsw comes from in the equation?

Comment: Fsw is your switching frequency,  20kHz in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your subquestion:

> **... I'm still trying to work out ... why I was told to put a diode there.**

If the load is inductive (either mainly an inductor but even if it is mainly resistive but partially inductive) then, when the MOSFET is turned off, an opposite polarity voltage will appear across the load. The diode conducts this current in a closed loop back through the inductor and the energy stored in the inductor is dissipated in the inductor's resistance and in the diode.
Without this diode an inductive energy driven voltage spike will occur as the energy in the inductor dissipates. In real world systems this spike can reach 100's or perhaps 1000's of volts 'if required'. In a circuit like this the voltage spike often contains enough energy to destroy the MOSFET and the diode stops this happening.

A 1N4148 will usually be far too "lightweight" for this applicatiom.

**____________________________________**

Consider a pure inductance for simplicity for now.
A fundamental property of an inductor is that  the current in it **CANNOT** change instantaneously. So, immediately after FET turnoff Iload will continue to flow through the inductor in the same direction as before.
If D1 is present then the current will flow through D1 forming a closed circuit path and the energy in the inductor (= 1/2 x L x I^2) will dissipate in the inductor resistance (loss = I^2 x Rinductor) and in the diode (loss = Vf_diode x I); If the diode is not present the current will "seek another path".
If there is no formal path the voltage across the inductor will rise (and rise and rise) until there is enough voltage to cause the required current to flow.
Voltages of hundreds of voltas can occur in real systems. In the abwence of any other path the energy usually ends up stored in stray capacitance such that
Energy = 1/2 x L x I^2 = 1.2 x C x V^2.
For small C (which is usually the case) V can be large.    In the low loss case the circuit will "ring" with energy alternatively being transferred between inductor and capacitor in a decaying oscillatory fashion.

In some cases the time taken to dissipate the inductive energy may be longer than is desired. Placing a resistance in series with the diode will increase dissipation by adding resistive losses (= i^2 x R_resistor, at the 'cost' of having the spike rise by the voltage across the resistor ( = i x R).